# The code plays BGM on only 64bit mode

Tags: objective-c

I want to play BGM. The below code plays BGM on *only 64bit mode*. What should I do?

```
- (void)playBgmLoop
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"aikatsu" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    audio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

    // Infinite loop
    audio.numberOfLoops = -1;

    [audio play];
}
@end
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Biannual General Meeting?  ("Roop"??)

Comment: @HotLicks give 'em a break; clearly a transliteration problem. Also BGM == [background music](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_music#Video_game_and_blog_music).

Comment: @Mike - "Background music" was about halfway down the Google page.  And I can't tell if the guy simply misspelled "loop", is spelling it "phonetically", or is trying to be "cute".

Comment: (Most likely there is no resource by that name found in the 32-bit environment.)

Comment: @weed, first of all, can you check the return values of all the calls you make? Are each `path`, `url`, or `audio` non-nil? The `play` method returns `BOOL`; is it true or false? Can you pass an pointer to a `NSError*` into [initWithContentsOfURL:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL:error:) and check if an error code is set?